# Using Firestore calls with Swift AwaitKit?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to move away from "closure hell" and implement AwaitKit/PromiseKit in my Firestore calls.

I get the error `Cannot invoke 'await' with an argument list of type '(Void)'` on the code snippet below (AwaitKit 5.0)

```
func create(user: User) {
    let userData = usersEngine.createNewUserDictionary(for: user)
    try await(db.collection("users").document(user.ID).setData(userData))
}
```

The AwaitKit docs seem a little sparse on examples/usage. Has anyone gotten it to work with Firestore and/or have code examples I could reference?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying just with semaphores? Like:

```
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    queue.async {

        // Some code here...
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    let _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + 2.0)

    queue.async {

        // ...and here.
    }
```

You can read about the approach [here](https://medium.com/@poksi/synchronysing-the-asynchronous-in-swift-3f91a32bfb1b).